# Get at tags for blog posts programmatically

Tags: ruby, blogs

I wonder how to get at tags in blog posts (WordPress, Blogger, or Blogspot) programmatically (API, RSS feed, XML, other methods). Preferably a solution usable in Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 1):

See what the life streaming Rails apps such as [kakuteru](http://github.com/dominiek/kakuteru) are using.  Tagging across multiple Web2.0 style streams is important to kakuteru and I think they may employ a number of techniques.  The also employ [zemanta](http://developer.zemanta.com/) which has an API to generate tags from content.  You can see [zemanta's example of getting tags using ruby](http://developer.zemanta.com/wiki/helloworld/ruby)

Answer (score 0):

If either of those have an API, i'd start by reading their documentation; outside of that; you can roll your own screenscraper (which is likely to be useless, given the amount of DOM content that is script generated these days)

[Wordpress API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API)

[Blogger API](http://www.blogger.com/developers/api/1_docs/)